# Build dynamic URLs in React based on input

Tags: reactjs, url, filter, redux, react-router

I have a list of items and I want to filter through them.

In order to do so I have a filtering component that looks like this:

```
[ text input "item name" ] [ dropdown "item category" ] [ date picker ]
```

I'm using React with Redux, react-redux and react-router. There's no "Filter" in my component, I want the items to get filtered as I type.

First of all I'm not sure how should I dynamically create the URL, so for example if you type "Abc" in the first input I want the current URL to be:

`http://example.com/currentPage?filter=Abc&category=&dates=`

As I type I want the URL to be changing constantly, so the URL actually builds as I type / choose options from dropdown / date picker. How could I achieve that with React Router?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so straightforward. Just add onChange function to your input field. Like below.

```
import React from 'react';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      filter: '',
      category: '',
      dates: '',
    }
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
      filter: evt.target.value,
    }, () => {
      this.props.fetchFilteredItems(`http://example.com/currentPage?filter=${this.state.filter}&category=${this.state.category}&dates=${this.state.dates}`); // I assumed fetchFilteredItems comes from redux as an action.
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <YourDropdown />
        <YourDatePicker />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Do you think using "setState" within Redux-based app is a good idea? Because it surely seems like an anti-pattern. Also what if someone just enters `http://example.com/currentPage?filter=Abc&category=&dates=` - nothing happens, because there is no change to the input.

Comment: I just added it to show you the demo code. Anyhow you can have the redux state already available in your props. Just use to get it done in place of the `setState` function.